# What is the CamelContext in apache?

Tags: apache-camel

I searched in web but did not find any explanation that what is the exactly CamelContext? where and how to use ?

I gone through below links also but not satisfied with explanation.
https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html
https://dzone.com/articles/apache-camel-tutorial-eip

There are many comparision for CamelContext with others, but what I am looking for is the what is it? I want some conceptual explanation. 
Please help me to understand this.

Comment: refer this link for camel context in apache :http://camel.apache.org/camelcontext.html

Comment: @Reena, I gone through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the videos in YouTube, I knew about the Apache camel framework, 
and from that I got the answer that camelcontext is nothing but context of the 'apache camel framework' framework.

As many framework have context like Spring have an applicationcontext, Ninja have a context, same the 'Apache camel framework' have a context and that is called 'camelcontext'.

So, it is the run-time system of Apache Camel (framework) and it connects its different concepts such as routes, components or endpoints.

Reference : 
[Basic Apache Camel Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK0V_H0fCvPilK2_-WMwahm7HYB0XgJx7)

Answer (score 2):

It's roughly an instance of a Camel environment, or at least it's a reference to it. Most apps would only have one CamelContext, but you can have several if needed. Looking at the referenced document, it shows how the context has a lifecycle.

In most cases, the context will start and stop along with the application.